# Do these river names mean anything?

Tags: etymology, names

I was planning a little trip the other day when I noticed that a number of rivers in Britain have common names. The ones I spotted were *Avon*, *Ouse* and *Esk*. Is there a reason for this? Are these names derived from something?

Comment: *Ouse* is quite probably related to the PIE **wed-* or **ud-*, meaning *water* as an inanimate substance (whence *whiskey*, the Greek *ύδωρ* (*hydro-*), the English *water*, the German *Wasser* (water), the Russian *вода* (water), *ведро* (bucket), *выдра* (otter), the Latin *onda* (wave), the German *Undine*, etc.). Not sure about the others.

Comment: For the specifics, Ward gave an excellent answer. There are other similar anomalies in place names in the British Isles. One of my favourites is Pendle Hill. The word 'pen' means hill. Later, the next incomers changed the hill's name to 'Pendle', meaning 'hill hill'. And then the next incomers, not knowing the etymology (and sadly lacking an internet) called it Pendle Hill or 'hill hill hill', so Pendle Hill really, really, really is a hill, because anything said three times is the truth.

Comment: But anything said *four* times is apparently too good to be true, alas: [Torpenhow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torpenhow_Hill) [Hill](http://www.thefreelibrary.com/The+debunking+of+Torpenhow+Hill.-a098250320)

Comment: Good Lord. It's these tiny gems of knowledge buried in comments that keep me coming back to this site. I wonder what [Linguistics.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6673/linguistics?referrer=ESkGjQfvvh_Wgagw76fBpg2) will come up with. Languages are freaking fascinating (and that should be in bold, italics, and all-uppercase). @PLL.

Comment: @PLL: I hadn't heard that one - but your URL led me to Wikipedia's [List of tautological place names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tautological_place_names) which does include 'Pendle Hill' amongst its celebrities - though I knew of that independently of Wikipedia.

Comment: Of course, the river names mean something or meant something. This kind of etymology is the task of name research - I don't know the English scientific term for it at the moment. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/?title=List_of_river_name_etymologies#Europe

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### [Avon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/River_Avon,_Warwickshire#Etymology)

> "Avon" derives from the British language abona, "river", which also survives as a number of other English and Scottish river names, and as modern Welsh afon (pronounced [ˈavɔn]), "river".

### [Ouse](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Ouse+River)

> The English name for the river derives from its Celtic name Usa, from *udso-, "water," which derives from the Indo-European root *wed-, "wet, water" (and the same root from which we derive water and wet). Thus the Ouse River etymologically is the "Water River" or the "Wet River." Of course, the English who borrowed the name from the Celts did not know the meaning of the wordas is rather frequently the case when foreign topographical terms are borrowed.

### [Esk](https://heraldry.sca.org/names/engplnam.html)

> At the same time the river names Axe, Exe, Esk and Usk are all derived from the British word isca meaning "water".

---

It would seem none of the naming was very original to begin with.

Comment: There are at least 10 French cities named "Aix" (Aix-en-Provence being the best known), also from the old French for "water".  I guess there were springs or baths there.

Comment: It has always amused me that 'River Avon' translates to 'River River'. Little things please little minds :)

Comment: @chimp: My mother is a geographer, I think I was first amused with that when I was about 5, lol.

Comment: It doesn't surprise me that there are rivers named River River - having visited Loch Lochy in Scotland and Llyn Llyn in Wales :)

Comment: @chimp -- you'd love [Torpenhow Hill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torpenhow_Hill). "Tor", "pen", and "how" all mean "hill".

Comment: Unfortunately [not so](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10488/do-these-river-names-mean-anything?rq=1#comment65627_10488), @Malvolio. I'd recognise *abhainn* and *uisce* from modern Irish, by the way.

Comment: @TRiG -- apparently, _some_ people didn't get the memo about "too good to check".

Comment: This answer is a bit confusing because it refers to the [Brythonic Celtic language family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brittonic_languages) variously as "British" and "Celtic". England, Wales, and southern Scotland spoke closely-related Celtic languages until replaced in most areas by Anglo-Saxon in the mid-late 1st millennium CE; these languages persisted in more remote areas and evolved into Welsh, Cornish, and Breton. All three names discussed are from Brythonic Celtic.

Answer (score 1):

Esk or,  Exe from isca I suggest is "Celtic" related to "pisces" hence "fish river".
Axe is said not to be cognate with Exe.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U and thanks for your contribution. If you have them, it is helpful if you are able to provide references or other substantiation for your suggestions, so we know that they are not just your personal opinion. Also what does "isca" mean?

Comment: British _Isca_ is not related to _piscis_. The Insular Celtic cognate to _piscis_ was _*ēsko-_, which with the regular diphthongisations of _ē_ gave Old Irish _íasc_ (gen. _éisc_) and Proto-British _*oesk-_ > Welsh _wysg_. _Isca_ goes rather with Old Irish _uisce_ and is from _*u(d)skio-_ > Proto-British _*üskjo-_ > _*isko-_ (since lost in the currently extant British languages, where the ‘other’ word for water is used: Welsh _dŵr_ (Old Welsh _dwfyr_), Breton _dowr_, Old Irish _dobur).

Answer (score 1):

I'm originally from Harrogate, North Yorks, so my local river was the Nidd, which means "sparkling".

These days, I live in Perth, Western Australia, where the Swan River flows. Before becoming the Swan River, however, it is known as the Avon River, named after the Avon in England, which of course means River River. Funnily enough though, here it's pronounced the old British way with a short "A"' ie "Avvon", rather than "Ayvon".

Answer (score -3):

The word 'ESK' almost certainly has origins much more ancient than Celtic tradition. I suspect the word derives from ancient biblical texts which references 'ESEK', a spring or well of water. ESEK first appears in Genesis 26 as the name given by Isaac to a well dug by his people. Local herdsmen, jealous of Isaacs growing wealth and influence, contested the wells dug byIsaac as a means of controlling their prosperity. In biblical times, the word 'Esek' literally meant 'contested'.

As the Old Testament narrative spread through northern Europe, words and place names were adopted. Indeed, in the 'ESK' valley of The Borough of Angus, where the rivers South and North Esk flow, sits the village of 'Padanaram', referenced in the very same Chapter of Genesis as the well-spring 'ESEK'.

Comment: Are you contending that the Celtic Isca is derived from an ancient Hebrew reference?  How do you justify that?

Comment: Genesis was written c 550BCE to c. 350BCE. The Brittonic peoples occupied Britain from c. 800 BCE. You seem to be the victim of an anachronism. Christianity reached Britain c. 597 AD

Comment: To add: the "Map of the County of Forfar or Shire of Angus." (Edinburgh : Ainslie, 1794) does not show  'Padanaram' - it seems a recent settlement...